# Is there a way to find out the maximum allowed email size configured by an email server?

Tags: email

An email server of a customer only allows emails of a maximum size.
This size is settable by the admin of course.

Is there a way to find out this setting?

I can send an email to one address, but I prefer not to.

I can ask the customers IT, but I prefer not to.

Is there a way for a person not inside the customers company (and not having an email account inside customers company) to find this out?

Comment: Not sure this is a good fit here considering it has to do with commercial server configuration. Voting to migrate. IMO, email is not a good file transfer tool. If you are concerned your email might be rejected, and you are unwilling to ask, then I would suggest using a file sharing service.

Answer (score 0):

The initial server response might have a line about it (`SIZE`) if you `HELO` or `EHLO` him. You could use something like a `telnet` client to connect and check it. A mail client or similar won't usually show you that kind of information. Check this question to find some more information: [How to retrieve fixed upper limit on message size SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006226/how-to-retrieve-fixed-upper-limit-on-message-size-smtp-server)

Don't forget that file attachment to emails need to be encoded and this usually involves some overhead. In addition the message itself will take some bytes.

Comment: The OP stated "*for a person not inside the customers company*". Will this work for that?

Comment: It should work with any mail server that is accessible from the internet. There are configurations that suppress certain information or filters in place etc. so if it's impossible for him to connect he won't have a chance to figure that information out short of calling someone at that company/sending an email.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to talk to their IT. Many providers give this information out any way in their documents/FAQ pages etc

However, you can work it out with trial and error... Send an email with an attachment of 1MB attachment. Then another with 5MB. Then 10MB, 15, 20, 25, 50 etc (you choose the increment)...

Of course, what limit is there today isn't *necessarily* there tomorrow.